# Why am I not able to use continue with a label with Collections#forEach in Java 8?

Tags: java, for-loop, java-8, label

Following compiles without any errors:

```
class App {
    boolean b;
    boolean c;

    void foo(List<Integer> ints) {
        myLabel:
        for (Integer i : ints) {
            while (!b) {
                if (c) {
                    continue myLabel;
                }
            }
        };
    }
}
```

But if I modify `foo` as follows:

```
void foo(List<Integer> ints) {
    myLabel:
    ints.forEach(integer -> {
        while (!b) {
            if (c) {
                continue myLabel;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

I get `Error:(17, 21) undefined label: myLabel`

What is the difference? As far as I know, the new `forEach` is just a shortcut for the enhanced for loop?

Comment: Because you're in a separate (lambda) function.

Comment: *" the new forEach is just a shortcut for the enhanced for loop?"* - No, not really, it's a method which takes a closure which can perform an operation on the element which is passed to it

Comment: @SLaks but you can access variables outside lambda. why not a label? I wonder if the JLS specifies this

Comment: I actually tried `final myLabel` thinking the same thing, which obviously itself a syntax error. @Eugene

Comment: Syntactically it's completely different, it's just a method invocation. Labels are meant to work with loops not method invocations.

Comment: @Eugene: Because they're captured in a closure.  That has nothing to do with control flow; how would it even make sense to jump across functions? What if the lambda is called later?

Comment: @SLaks yeah... I realized that after posting the comment

Comment: Note that you can achieve the desired result with the lambda expression, when you replace `continue myLabel;` with `return;`. Control flow statements within a lambda expression are best understood when thinking of the lambda body as some kind of nested *method*.

Comment: @Holger Very useful information, thank you for commenting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As stated in the comments, `forEach` is just a method invocation. The snippet

```
myLabel: ints.forEach(integer -> ...);
```

is a [labeled statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.7):

> identifier statement labels are used with `break` or `continue` statements (§14.15, §14.16) appearing anywhere within the labeled statement.

To repeat, the labeled statement is the method invocation expression. Your `continue` statement is not within the labeled statement.

Your [`continue` statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.7) is within a `while` statement appearing within the body of a lambda expression.

> A `continue` statement with label `Identifier` attempts to transfer
>   control to the enclosing labeled statement (§14.7) that has the same
>   `Identifier` as its label; that statement, which is called the continue
>   target, then immediately ends the current iteration and begins a new
>   one.
>
> [...]
>
> The continue target must be a `while`, `do`, or `for` statement, or a compile-time error occurs.
>
> A `continue` statement must refer to a label within the immediately
>   enclosing method, constructor, initializer, or lambda body. There are
>   no non-local jumps. **If no labeled statement with `Identifier` as its
>   label in the immediately enclosing method, constructor, initializer,
>   or lambda body contains the continue statement, a compile-time error
>   occurs**.

Since there is no labeled (`while`, `do`, or `for`) statement named `myLabel` in the immediately enclosing lambda body, you get a compile-time error.